# Proof of the structure theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading through Ian Stewart's book "Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem" (3rd edition) and I'm having trouble with a bit of the proof of Theorem 1.16 (page 29). The part I don't understand is the statement that since $\alpha_1$ is chosen to be minimal the remainders $r_i$ are all zero.

Context: Let $G$ be a free abelian group of rank $n>1$. Take $h \ne 0 $ to be some element of a subgroup $H$. If $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ is a basis for $G$ then $h = h_1w_1 + \cdots + h_nw_n$ where $h_i$ not all zero. We then let $\alpha_1$ be the minimal $h_i$ for any basis. The book then goes on to state that if we take an element $v_1 \in H$ such that $v_1$ has $\alpha_1$ occurring as a coefficient, i.e. $$v_1 = \alpha_1w_1 + \beta_2 w_2 + \cdots + \beta_nw_n,$$ then $\alpha_1 $ must divide each $\beta_i$ (as a result of the minimality of $\alpha_1$). This is what I mean above by "the remainders $r_i$ are all zero".

My questions are:
1) Why is such a minimal $\alpha_1$ guaranteed to exist? It seems like we can always scale to get a smaller (i.e. negative) $\alpha_1$.
2) Why does the minimality of $\alpha_1$ guarantee that $r_i = 0$, where $\beta_i = \alpha_1q_i + r_i$, for all $2\le i \le n$?